# Transmitting data using iBeacon or similar technology

Tags: java, android, ios, ibeacon

I am working on an app that allows devices to become aware of each other when in range. To do this i am using iBeacon.

In the next stage of development i want to be able to send a yes or no string between any of the devices in range - so anyone who is connected to any other iBeacon can communicate these fixed messages

As iBeacon cannot support sending of data - what is the best approach to facilitate this. The 2 approaches i have at the moment are via bluetooth or a web service.

Please could someone provide some advise on to what is the best approach.

Comment: did you already have the part where one iphone detects other iphone using beacon technologie?

Comment: detection is fine, the issue is once the beacon identifies another is in proximity - how can you communicate between them

Comment: i would use a webservice, because i would not like the user to manually connect/pair to wlan/bluetooth and a web service could used over the air.

Comment: It's untrue that an "iBeacon" cannot send data.  Simply changing a few bits of the major/minor numbers allows you to communicate a small amount of information - for example, make any even number mean "no" and any odd number mean "yes".   There's also nothing that keeps you from having additional services beyond the manufacturer unique data field which makes it an "iBeacon".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either approach can work, but a web service has real advantages:

1. Connecting to a bluetooth service requires user permission, a web service does not.
2. If your app is not running in the foreground, the iBeacon monitoring API can make it launch into the background for about 5 seconds.  During this time you can call a web service.  But background support for bluetooth connections is limited in iOS.
3. If the bluetooth connection is directly between devices, you have to figure out which device to make the central and which to make the peripheral.  This negotiation is complex.
4. If the bluetooth connection is between each device and the beacon, then you can't use standard iBeacons -- you have to build custom ones that support additional connectable bluetooth services.

The main disadvantage of a web service approach is that it won't work when you don't have network connectivity.  You have to decide if you can live with that disadvantage.