# Send additional data in iBeacon

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am working on an iBeacon project where I want to send text informations along with iBeacon data. I am now using iPhone as iBeacon. I can't find a way to customise the data transmission as well as reception using CoreLocation.

I am able to do this if both sender and receiver are of Bluetooth mode. I have gone through similar questions ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132524/how-to-send-some-data-between-ibeacons), [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799917/transmitting-data-using-ibeacon-or-similar-technology)) and these are different from what I want.

Comment: which company's beacon you are using?

Comment: If the firmware transmit these data, will I be able to read the additional data?

Comment: they will provide you there own sdk for accessing that data. some other beacon provider provide these information.

Comment: ok. I haven't researched on beacon device vendors and their services and sdks. It is good to know that they may provide sdks for their beacons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with iBeacon alone. You will need your device to act as an iBeacon and a BLE peripheral. Once you enter the beacon region you will need to initiate a connection to the BLE peripheral using Core Bluetooth in order to read the additional characteristics.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11. This will help me to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: This is correct.  There are two reasons you cannot add the extra fields to an iBeacon advertisement and read the fields on iOS: 1. BLE advertisements have a limited length, and the iBeacon format only slows one extra byte to be added before hitting the max length.  2. CoreLocation and CoreBluetooth do not let you read the raw bytes of an iBeacon advertisement.

Comment: I would expose the beacon identifiers (uuid/major/minor) as a separate GATT characteristic so you can identify each beacon when connecting via CoreBluetooth.

Comment: @davidgyoung, thank you. Now I got an idea of how to configure my beacon as well as my app.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik please stop adding code tags to words that aren't code.

Answer (score 0):

I have already work on `jaalee beacon`, its working like a push notification also.

```
//start Monitoring for beacon

locationManager:(JLEBeaconManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(JLEBeaconRegion *)region
{

    [manager requestStateForRegion:region];
    [beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
}

//Enter method

beaconManager:(JLEBeaconManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(JLEBeaconRegion *)region

//Exit method

beaconManager:(JLEBeaconManager *)manager didExitRegion:(JLEBeaconRegion *)region
```